# Local db fails and changes over to cloud db?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, azure, cloud

Is it possible to run a local db with cloud backup where if the local db fails it changes over to cloud, so that new data stores in cloud until the failure is resovled, and then once resolved new data is copied to the local db and then the system resumes to use the local db. Any solution can be accepted ie aws or azure but how do i set it up where the db login address and configuration within the application stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot and according my experience, there isn't any tools or Azure Service can do that.

I think it's impossible for now.